# XLSX Reader: Caught exception: Failed to open test.xlsx with zip error code: 11

Tags: php, xlsx

I've used XLSXReader.php to read the content in a xlsx sheet. This is my code:

```
require_once('XLSXReader.php');
$path = 'test.xlsx';

try {
 // Read xls
 $xls = new XLSXReader($path);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 p("Caught exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
return false;
}

$sheets = $xls->getSheetNames();
print_r($sheets);exit;
```

When I tried to execute the above code, I got an error "**Caught exception: Failed to open test.xlsx with zip error code: 11**".

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This `XLSXReader` library obviously expects the `xlsx` file to be in fact a ZIP file. See [XLSXReader.php#L45](https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader/blob/10cad4e800adc1f7793c4bbfb2dd1e730f0735b7/XLSXReader.php#L45).

I'm not expert on `xlsx` file format's but your file might not be a valid `xlsx` (maybe it's just `xls` renamed to `xlsx`).

Answer (score 0):

This error will also occur if you don't have the correct filepath. Make sure you are not referencing a missing file.